# Would a Medal of Valour burn a Malvora?

Tags: dresden-files

Since House Malvora of the White Court are fear-eaters, they've got a weakness to "selfless courage".

I was just wondering if, along with an allergy to a *person* exhibiting that, if like the Raith's being liable to also have a bad reaction to some *objects* that represent their weakness (like some wedding rings)  - might a member of the Malvora family also be liable to be burned too by something like a "Medal of Valour", were they to touch it?

Comment: Are you a GM, player, or just curious about the system?

Comment: @Ifusaso New player who is new to and learning about the system! It’s not come up yet so this isn’t pressing, but I’m admittedly curious all the same! Sorry I didn’t clarify.

Comment: No worries, it's just that type of information can color answers.

Comment: @Ifusaso, right, thank you! I will keep that advice in mind for the future too then :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your assessment is accurate for the source content; specifically, the author [Jim Butcher's quote](http://wordof.jim-butcher.com/index.php/word-of-jim-woj-compilation/woj-on-vampires/) about the various White Court weaknesses confirms that courage and symbols of it would be their weakness.

“You’ve said that True Love (real True Love) only protects against WCVamps feeding on lust. What protects against the other WCVamps?”

> It isn’t real complicated that way. **The vamps who feed on fear get bad effects from real courage.** Those who feed on despair choke on hope.

Furthermore, from Dresden Files RPG Volume one "Your Story" (p84)

> Hey, Bob, is it only True Love that works here, or are there other...uh, Truths?

> One could easily posit that True, and most importantly, selfless Hope or Courage would act as dire counters to despair and fear. But we have a decided lack of, shall we say, experimental data on that front.

> **For game purposes, it makes sense if other True emotions work, so I’m going to go with that.**

---

However, the exact situation of the Medal of Valor might also affect its ability to repel a Malvora:

- Was the Medal justly earned, or was it given to someone for simply surviving?
- Is the Medal viewed by the recipient as a true representation of their courage?
- Is the Medal a current representation, or something that has been passed down for generations?
- Has the medal been held in reverence, or was it just unpacked from a dusty cardboard box?

If the Medal truly represents courage to the person who received or currently has it, it can repel a Malvora similarly to Love repelling a Raith. Otherwise, it may not actually embody the courage you may think. The exact effect of this is not elucidated, but a few things are listed as consequences:

- "True [emotion] can burn them (leaving scars that don’t fade), and holy objects
  and displays of faith at least make them uncomfortable." (YS p84)
- The character's Inhuman Toughness and Inhuman Recovery would be compromised as True [Emotion] would be their Catch (YS p84 & p185)
- This only officially applies to directly using the Medal against them, although most people would probably run it as a compel against the character's High Concept to remove themselves from its presence... or a Block against them doing anything while it's in contact with them.

Notably, Raiths don't immediately flee from everyone wearing a ring so it can be assumed that, although the presence of it would make them uncomfortable, merely having the Medal wouldn't immediately scare off a Malvora. Even the intent to use it against them wouldn't necessarily mean they don't simply attempt to knock you out instead.

Comment: Your wording is rather vague and ambiguous when applied to the concept of posthumous medals.  I'd suggest that the key here is very similar to thresholds, in that it's a function of belief over time.  If the person holding it believes it represents courage -- and I mean genuinely believes it, and interacts (if only by viewing) the medal on a regular basis, then the medal should gain that virtue.  If it's shoved into a dusty corner and forgotten, that virtue would fade over time.

Comment: I left it ambiguous for that very reason, actually. Using the FATE system, ambiguity isn't necessarily the worst thing. I could add a little more detail, I suppose.